# Does default value as internationalized string would make a component impure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming

I have a React application which is using `react-intl` for handing internationalization.

There is a generic `Input` component like this:

```js
const Input = ({ placeholder = formatMessage({ id: 'app.defaultPlaceholder' }) }) => (
    <input placeholder={placeholder} />
)
```

My question is - Does giving a default value like this to placeholder would make this component Impure ?